# Making this arraycopy more efficient

Tags: java, performance, array

I'd like to find out how I can make my function more efficient:

```
public boolean addAll(int i, Collection<? extends T> c) {
    for (T x : c)
        add(i++, x);
    return true;
}

public void add(int i, T x) {
    if (n + 1 > a.length) resize();
    System.arraycopy(a, i, a, i+1, n-i);
    a[i] = x;
    n++;
}

protected void resize() {
    T[] b = f.newArray(Math.max(2 * n,1));
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, n);
    a = b;
}
```

I'm not sure what else I can do to implement a more efficient way to use my `addAll()` function.

Answer (score 4):

As [@Brythan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/53820/brythan) suggested, you should rename your variables. I propose:

- `arr` instead of `a`
- `size` instead of `n`
- `index` instead of `i`
- `copy` instead of `b`
- `items` or `elements` or `collection` instead of `c`

I suppose that `addAll` returns a boolean to mimic the behavior of [`Collections.addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)). That is all well, except you're not actually implementing that behavior, only the method signature. The JavaDoc says:

> **Returns:**
>
> `true` if the collection changed as a result of the call

So you should change your implementation accordingly. Perhaps something like this:

```
public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> items) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (size + items.size() > arr.length) {
        resize(2 * (size + items.size()));
    }
    System.arraycopy(arr, index, arr, index + items.size(), size - index);
    for (T item : items) {
        arr[index++] = item;
    }
    size += items.size();
    return true;
}
```

This also includes my naming suggestions, as well as Brythan's advice to avoid calling `add` one by one for each element. For the resizing, I added a helper method and refactored the existing one like this:

```
private void resize() {
    resize(Math.max(2 * size, 1));
}

private void resize(int targetSize) {
    T[] copy = newArray(targetSize);
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, copy, 0, size);
    arr = copy;
}
```

(Since I don't know what was "f" in your original `f.newArray`, I wrote my own `newArray`.)

Notice that I changed the visibility of `resize` to `private`.
This is an internal operation that shouldn't be accessible by any other class by default.

Finally, by the same logic of `addAll` (following existing examples), `add` should also return `boolean`: `true` if the collection was modified. (In your case always.)

Answer (score 2):

First, this would be easier if you named things more descriptively.  I don't know enough about `a` to suggest a name.  For `i` though, it should be called something like `currentPosition`.  For `n`, something like `aCount` if the array is still named `a`.

You are calling `add` on every member of your collection.  This could potentially do two `System.arraycopy` calls and a memory allocation for every member.  Instead, `addAll` should do the same things that `add` does only it should do it for the entire collection at once.  That gets us down to two `System.arraycopy` calls and a memory allocation total.

```
if (n + 1 > a.length) resize();
System.arraycopy(a, i, a, i+1, n-i);
```

Rewrite these for `addAll`.

> Hint:  the 1 is incorrect for `addAll`.  Replace the 1 with the appropriate value based on the collection.

```
a[i] = x;
n++;
```

These are mostly correct.  You can put them in the `for` loop that you are using to call `add` in your current code.  There needs to be one change in the first line to make it work.

You can also take the `n++` out of the `for` loop and rewrite it into a single statement if you want.

> Hint:  `n++` is the equivalent of `n += 1` and we already discussed that 1 is wrong for `addAll`.

Finally, you never `return false` from `addAll`.  Why make it return anything at all?